# New cam sensor - car won't start (Tucson 2006 diesel)

Tags: hyundai, cranks-wont-run, camshaft, camshaft-position-sensor

I own a 2006 Hyundai Tucson CRDi 2.0. Starting the engine has become slow recently, and the shop diagnosed it to a bad camshaft sensor. I bought a new one and replaced the old. With the new one in place, the car won't even start. It sounds like it tries to start, but when releasing the key it dies out.

I think I did everything right; disconnected battery negative, disconnected old sensor, replaced and plugged the cables back in.

With the old sensor in place, the car starts (abit slowly after cranking for a bit).

Any ideas what might cause this? Might it be the ECU not recognizing the new sensor

Comment: Is it possible the new sensor is defective?  Is it possible the new sensor is not the correct model?

Comment: It's unlikely the new sensor is defective, but defective-out-of-the-box is not unheard of.

Comment: " defective-out-of-the-box is not unheard of" agree, I see this all the time.

Comment: Purchase one from Hyundai.